# Ignoring a warning in a loop and continuing

Tags: matlab, solver

I have three vectors A, B, and C. For each value in these vectors I would like to solve the equation C^x = A^x + B^x. Unfortunately this is an equation that I have found to be solvable only iteratively, so I am attempting to use MATLAB's "solve" function to find a solution for each case. My code is as follows:

```
exponents = zeros(100,1);

syms x

A = rand(100,1);
B = rand(100,1);
C = rand(100,1);

for i = 1:100

exponents(i) = eval(solve(C(i)^x == A(i)^x + B(i)^x));

end
```

Sometimes, however, the solution is unobtainable, which leads to the error message, "Warning: Explicit solution could not be found." I am okay with this, but if I run into an unsolvable equation, I would like to simply leave the "exponents(i)" unchanged for that iteration and move onto the next one, instead of having my code abruptly stop. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you put the statement that causes the occasional error inside a try/catch statement, then the error will not cause execution to stop.  For example, you could try:

```
for i = 1:100
  try
    exponents(i) = eval(solve(C(i)^x == A(i)^x + B(i)^x));
  catch
    exponents(i) = NaN; 
  end;
end
```

Comment: Yes, but the problem is s/he's receiving a warning, not an error.

Comment: That was actually a mistake on my part - I didn't know there was a nomenclature difference between "warning" and "error". This solved my problem perfectly. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

There is not a direct way in MATLAB for catching warnings (at least a documented way). It is not elegant in the slightest, if not downright ugly, you can try polling the output of [`lastwarn`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/lastwarn.html).

```
...
exponents(i) = eval(solve(C(i)^x == A(i)^x + B(i)^x));
[~, msgid] = lastwarn;
if strcmp(msgid, YOURWARNINGID)
    continue;
end
```

There is a similar post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3701673/how-can-i-continue-with-a-loop-when-an-error-occurs-in-matlab), except the poster was getting an error.